# Root weights and states in orbifold compactifications

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, compactification

I  have the following question regarding orbifold compactifications of the heterotic string:

What is the relation between a certain representation and the weights of the root lattice? I mean: take the following example from Uranga & Ibañez's book:

[image]

I understand that the possible weights of the $\left [ E_{6}\times SU(3) \right ]\times E_{8}{}'$ are $0,1$ and $2$ and each of them should correspond to one state $(\mathbf{27},\boldsymbol{3};\mathbf{1}'),(\mathbf{27},\mathbf{1};\mathbf{1}')$ or $(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{\bar{3}};\mathbf{1}')$.

*But which is this correspondece (and why)?*

Comment: You should study and understand weights for something simple like SU(3) before trying to understand something this complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each *dominant weight* corresponds to an irreducible representation for which it is the *highest weight*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_of_the_highest_weight

Weights are vectors in the root space, usually written in the basis of the *fundamental weights* so that all components are integral.

In the case you’re talking about, they aren’t just integers like 0, 1, and 2. The weight these authors are talking about is

$$\frac{1}{3}(1,1,2,0,...,0)\times(0,...,0)$$

The part after the $\times$ is the $E_8’$ part of the weight vector, corresponding to a 1-dimensional irrep. The part before must be a weight vector for $E_6\times SU(3)$ but I don’t know why it is written as a single vector or why it has a prefactor of 1/3.